# How to stop GridLayout from pushing things up when a view is removed

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

So I have the GridLayout (When adding a `View` I don't mess with params), and whenever I remove a `View` that is directly inside of the layout, it just removes it and pushing everything forward, so when I try to add another `View` it appends it, instead of adding it where I wanted.

i.e:

0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I want to remove 1, and add a 2. Now it's

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you removing the child view? One option would be something like this:

```
int index= yourIndex;
View newChild = (View) findViewById(R.id.childTwo);
GridLayout parent = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentId;
View child = (View) parent.getChildAt(index);
child.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
parent.addView(newChild, index);
parent.removeView(child);
```

Doing this will keep your placeholder in the GridLayout cell you want the new `View` to occupy, but this will only work if you are either adding the new `View` immediately after removing the existing one or if you don't mind having an "empty" looking cell in your GridLayout until whatever point in time you add the new `View` to it.

I haven't tested this exact code chunk but I do a very similar operation in one of my projects so hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

addview always put the new element at the end of a ViewGroup.

You can first add programatically mxn RelativeLatouts (or another ViewGroup) to the GridLayout and then removeViews from these layouts instead the GridLayout

Comment: So does that mean the only way is to add a layout to occupy the GridLayout then place my stuff inside of those layouts?

Answer (score 0):

Use [addView(View child, int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int)), and pass the new view and the index.